# application.run (macro,Arg1,Arg2)

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to kindly request for assistance with the following issue:

I am trying to run a Macro that runs multiple macros but it is based on 2 Strings as follows:

```
Sub ExportDatatoCountriesSheets()

    Dim shtnme As String
    Dim country As String

    ' United States
    shtnme = "US"
    country = "United States"
    ' ClearLatestData
    Application.Run "ClearLatestData"
    ' FilterExportDataByCountry
    Application.Run "FilterExportDataByCountry"

    ' Japan
    shtnme = "JP"
    country = "Japan"
    ' ClearLatestData
    Application.Run "ClearLatestData"
    ' FilterExportDataByCountry
    Application.Run "FilterExportDataByCountry"

End Sub

'==============================================================

Sub ClearLatestData()

    Dim shtnme As String
    Dim country As String
    Sheets(CStr(shtnme)).Activate
    Columns("A:Z").Select
    Selection.Clear

End Sub

'==============================================================

Sub FilterExportDataByCountry
Sheets("WEEKLY DATA").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$G$240").AutoFilter Field:=3,    Criteria1:=CStr(country)
    Columns("A:G").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets(CStr(shtnme)).Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
```

However, I keep getting errors. I essentially would like to set the `ExportDatatoCountriesSheets` Macro to repeat while I enter the code and run the others by Application.Run

I've searched and closest solution is to run the Macro with arguments but when I define the arguments the macro does not run properly and error occurs.

```
Application.Run (ClearLatestData, shtnme = "US", country = "United States")
```

Please advise if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to call the "***ClearLatestData***" MACRO (`Sub`) you need to add the 2 parameters to the receiveing `Sub`. So the syntax should be:

```
Sub ClearLatestData(shtnme As String, country As String)
```

and inside the `Sub ClearLatestData` you will remove the 2 lines of declaring the `String` variables:

```
Dim shtnme As String
Dim country As String
```

To call `Sub ClearLatestData` with the `shtnme` and `country`, use:

```
Application.Run "ClearLatestData", shtnme, country
```

Or, a "cleaner" shorter version:

```
ClearLatestData shtnme, country
```

**Code**

```
Sub ExportDatatoCountriesSheets()

Dim shtnme As String
Dim country As String

' United States
shtnme = "US"
country = "United States"
' ClearLatestData
ClearLatestData shtnme, country ' <-- call the MACRO    
' FilterExportDataByCountry
Application.Run "FilterExportDataByCountry"

' Japan
shtnme = "JP"
country = "Japan"

' ClearLatestData
ClearLatestData shtnme, country ' <-- call the MACRO    
' FilterExportDataByCountry
Application.Run "FilterExportDataByCountry"

End Sub

' ================================================================

Sub ClearLatestData(shtnme As String, country As String)

    Sheets(CStr(shtnme)).Activate
    Columns("A:Z").Select
    Selection.Clear

End Sub
```

---

**Note**: it's recommended to stay away from `Activate`, `Select` and `Selection`, and use qualified `Worksheets`, `Range`s and other objects instead.

For instance, instead of the 3 lines below:

```
Sheets(CStr(shtnme)).Activate
Columns("A:Z").Select
Selection.Clear
```

You can use a single line (and it will be faster since you don't use `Activate` and `select`):

```
Sheets(shtnme).Columns("A:Z").Clear
```

Comment: Worked like a charm sir. Thanks for your assistance! Much appreciated.